# Scala : Select the Jackson JsonNode keys using Regex filter in a json

Tags: java, regex, scala, jackson, jsonnode

I have sample jsonNode data - Inputstr =

```
{
"a.b.c.d.e":"123",
"a[0].b.c.d[0].e":"123",
"a[0].b.c.d[1].e":"123",
"a[1].b.c.d[0].e":"123",
"a[1].b.c.d[1].e":"123",
"d.e.f"="789",
"x.y.z"="789"
}
```

I want to extract the keys having data in format a[0-9*].b[0-9*].c[0-9*].d[0-9*].e[0-9*].
Basically, the output should return me, 0 or more occurrences

```
[ a.b.c.d.e , a[0].b.c.d[0].e, a[0].b.c.d[1].e, a[1].b.c.d[0].e, a[1].b.c.d[1].e ].
```

So, what i did was

```
val json = ObjectMapper.readTree(Inputstr)
val itr = json.fieldNames
```

Now on this iterator of keys i want to create a generic regex which returns me the above output.

I tried but not working

```
val regex = """a\[[0-9\]]*.b\[[0-9\]]*.c\[[0-9\]]*.d\[[0-9\]]*.e\[[0-9\]]*""".r
while(itr.hasNext())
{
    val str= itr.next()
    regex.findAllIn(str)
}
```

I am stuck in creating the regex basically which can take [0-9]*, it should check for both the braces [  ] as well as presence of a digit from 0 to 9 inside the braces. Even if none exists, it should return me a.b.c.d.e as well.

I hope it makes sense.
Please let me know if any questions.

Comment: The regex pattern should look something like `"""a(\[[0-9]\])?\.b(\[[0-9]\])?\.c(\[[0-9]\])?\.d(\[[0-9]\])?\.e(\[[0-9]\])?""".r`.

Comment: Just a side note, to ease pattern changes across the segments in the future you could also assemble the regex pattern like `"abcde".map(_ +: "(\\[[0-9]\\])?").mkString("\\.").r`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`a(?:\[\d])?\.b(?:\[\d])?\.c(?:\[\d])?\.d(?:\[\d])?\.e(?:\[\d])?`](https://regex101.com/r/jn37lh/1/)

Should do the job, I included the `[0]` part inside of a non matching group that can be optional using `?`

Comment: Yes, this too worked, thanks a lot :)
I will embed the regex in my main code, if i face any issues, will come back again :)
Thank you so very much :)

Comment: Shouldn't the closing square brackets be escaped as well?

Comment: @TestMirror not needed if the first one is escaped, but you can do it for more clarity of course